# Testing if function behaves the same as known function

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a file `correct.py` where I can assume that all the methods defined in it are correct, and I want to test the methods in `student.py`.  This is assumed to contain the same methods as `correct.py`.

I'm trying to use the `unittest` module, and so far it seems like a lot of my tests will look like:

```
import correct
import student

def test_func(self):
    self.assertEquals(correct.func(<input>),student.func(<input>))
```

This will be done on a variety of inputs.  Is there some way I can define a function that I'll just have to run `f(<input>)` or `f(<input>,func)` to get this same behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a function like this:

```
def test(self, argument, func): 
    Fcorrect = getattr(correct, func)
    Fstudent = getattr(student, func)
    self.assertEquals(Fcorrect(argument), Fstudent(argument))
```

Simply pass your `<input>` of whatever type you want to the `argument`parameter and pass the functions name to the `func` parameter as a string.

For example to test the function `"foo"` with `3` as an argument you would do the following:

```
self.test("foo", 3)
```

Comment: Will I need to redefine this for each testing class I use?  For each "section" of the assignment I'm defining a class (as I think is the traditional practice).  So, there may be `class TestProblemXMethods(unittest.TestCase)` for multiple problems.  So, would it make sense to define this test within `unittest.TestCase` so it's imported to each testing class?

This seems to work, but I'm just hesitant to copy it multiple times as I'm guessing there's a better solution.